# Return numbers of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
I made an array with some numbers 

Number: function() {

                 var someArray = [3,3,1];

                     for (var i=0, item; item=someArray[i]; i++) {
                            return item;  }
                    }
                };
```

It only repeats the first number of the array when I call it.

```
newRound: function() {
            $('[data-round]').text(++this.round);
            this.sequence.push(this.Number());
            this.copy = this.sequence.slice(0);
            this.animate(this.sequence);
        },
```

Each round it should add one number of the array. But somehow I keep getting the first number of the array only.

Comment: Can you post your entire Javascript code?  Also, try using `console.log(tones)`.  That way `tones` will show up in your browser's console, so you can get a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: What are you looking for?  In the first function, you are just returning a random number, but in the second snippet, what do you expect to happen?  Should it return the first one, the second one, or a random one from the list perhaps?

Comment: Without context this question appears nonsensical. Take a deep breath, take a moment, and explain (clearly) what you *want* to happen. What happens instead? How does it *not* do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but this is a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/105/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tones = [1,3,4,5,3,4,5];
    var str = '';
    for (var i=0; i<tones.length; i++) {
        str += tones[i] + ' ';
    }
    alert(str);
</script>
```

pretty much tones is an array, so in this demo, i'm looping through the array and adding it to a string then displaying the string.

Comment: ive updated my question. Could you please look at it

Comment: @user3046900 you totally changed the question; this should be a new question. and i suggest you read whatever tutorial you are going through, because the code you have written in your question doesnt jive with each other. i also suggest you read up on how the stack overflow site works and how you're supposed to ask questions with clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you need numbers between 1 and 4, it would be better to do this:

```
randomNumber: function() {
// between 1 and 4
    return Math.floor(((Math.random() * 10000) % 4) + 1);
}
```